# How to pass href variables to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

So ive got a JS function that's run when multiple html href's are clicked. That is to say, i have about 4 different href's that look similar to this:

```
<a href='#' onClick="myPopup()">New Window</a>
```

and my JS looks like this :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
function myPopup() 
{
    window.open( "account_edit.php", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0" )   
}
//-->
</script>
```

my point is, i dont want to have to re-write that one block of script another 3 times. Is there a way i can get the script to tell which href was clicked, then open up its respective page? Obviously normal href's are out of the picture, else i would do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This doesn't help if you aren't using jQuery, but if you were: You can use `[jQuery.data]([http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)` method to extract an arbitrary value from your anchor tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function myPopup(target) 
{
    window.open( target, "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0" )
```

then call it from each `<a>` with a different target:

```
<a href='#' onClick="myPopup('account_edit.php')">New Window</a>
```

Bonus Track: you can make this unobtrusive with jquery (much cleaner!)

HTML:

```
<a href="account_edit.php">New Window</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //prevents browser from following link
        window.open( this.href, "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0" )
    });
});
```

note: if you don't specify a fqdn, the browser will prepend your current URL path to the href (so if you call this from abc.com/test/test.htm the popup will open in abc.com/test/account_edit.php)

Comment: Oh wow, im surprised i didnt remember that!! I havent wrote java in over a year! :/

Thanks man!!

Comment: I think you mean javascript =)

Comment: I trued to but it wouldnt let me and i had to wait but now it's okay :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could pass something unique through the parameter:

```
<a href='#' onClick="myPopup('link1')">New Window</a>
```

then here:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function myPopup(link) 
{
    alert('you cliked on link '+link); //or do whatever your want
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

just pass some arguments within your javascript function call like New Window, New Window and so on